# Need to Return MAX(DATE) that falls in a date range (usually 1 week) that is 1 month or more in the future

Tags: psql, dateadd, maxdate

I Have a table (`PM_ACTION_LOG`) for Maintenance records, the columns are `ITEM`, `PM_TYPE`, `LOCATION`, `DATE`

I need to get only records that are `MAX(DATE)` for each "item" that has been at least 1 month since last date. Date range is usually a week.

This is close but doesn't return past due missed dates that were not loggedp

```
Select ITEM,PM_TYPE,LOCATION,MAX(DATE) as Last_Date
FROM PM_ACTION_LOG 
Where PM_TYPE = 'PM - Monthly' and LOCATION = 'Cass'
and DATEADD(Month,1,DATE) between '2018-12-23' and '2018-12-29'
GROUP BY ITEM,PM_TYPE,LOCATION
```

I think there needs to be a join of some sort:

```
Select ITEM,PM_TYPE,LOCATION,MAX(DATE)
FROM PM_ACTION_LOG a 
WHERE PM_TYPE = 'PM - Monthly' and LOCATION = 'Cass'
GROUP by ITEM,PM_TYPE,LOCATION
INNER JOIN (Select ITEM,MAX(DATE)as LAST_DATE
FROM PM_ACTION_LOG b
Where DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATE) BETWEEN '2018-12-16' and '2018-12-22'
Group by ITEM,PM_TYPE,LOCATION)
on a.ITEM = b.ItEM
```

I want to get the LATEST Date for each item that is 30 days fromfrom the last date and falls in the date range. 
We pull up our preventive monthly maintenance for each week.

Comment: In which database are you trying this query? MS SQL, MySQL etc.?

Comment: Please [edit] to add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, sample data, and the output you're trying to obtain from that data.

Comment: pervasive SQL—-PSQL